# Amazon AWS Issue - MySQL Access from EC2

Tags: php, mysql, amazon-web-services, amazon-rds, amazon-vpc

I am working on an Android App with basic user signup/login. Currently I have got it working on my localhost with WAMP Server running.

I wanted to take it a step further by taking Amazon RDS (MySQL) instance and hosting my php files on some server (probably EC2 Instance) and allowing the Android App to make a HTTP Request to the php file, which inturn connects to the MySQL instance.

So far I have created a `MySQL Instance and an EC2 instance (with LAMP setup)`.
I am unable to connect to the MySQL instance from the EC2 instance ( I ssh into the EC2 via Putty, and tried to connect to MySQL instance using this command
`mysql -h devo.*.ap-southeast-1.rds.amazonaws.com -P 3306 -u mymasteruser -p`).

`I am able to access it from my laptop though.`

I think it is due to the `VPC security groups` setup, which I am unable to configure for the MySQL Instance.

The EC2 & RDS instance are in Singapore region. Here is a snapshot of the VPC I have:

[image]

Here is the error message I see in putty:

[image]

Any suggestions or links to some resources to sort this out would be highly appreciated.

Comment: Could you clarify that you are using the correct zone in the connection? You have "us-east-1" and mention that your RDS is in Singapore. Thanks

Comment: that was the structure of the command I was using. I copy pasted it from the AWS Docs. Edited the question with actual command.

Comment: Cool, thanks. Also, to cover the basics: in your EC2 VPC security group settings, do you have MySQL port open to your particular IP?

Comment: @VictorPerez how do I verify that? I followed the AWS Docs to setup MySQL Instance. If I remember it correctly, I mentioned 0.0.0.0 in IP Section to keep it open for all IP's

Comment: @VictorPerez I followed this: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/CHAP_GettingStarted.CreatingConnecting.MySQL.html. I also kept it "Publicly Visible".

Comment: this sounds like it belongs on [sf]

Comment: Yeah I think so now since you pointed out, how can I move it there?

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem. Here are the steps I followed.

1. Navigate to RDS Console. Click the Database Instance. You would see a screen like this:[image]

2. Click on the `Security Groups` tab. Click on `Inbound -> Edit -> Change the Source to 0.0.0.0\0`

[image]